# Bash script local variable naming when read from ENV variable

Tags: bash, shell

For bash scripts, I generally follow the rule that local variables should be lowercase and environment variables should be uppercase. This is so I can avoid overwriting an environment variable by accident. I'm writing a Tomcat start script and I created a tomcat_log variable partially from an environment variable.

```
tomcat_log=${TOMCAT_HOME}/logs/tomcat-initd.log
```

Now I want to read in an environment variable with a possible default. Should this be uppercase or lowercase?

```
# uppercase
CONNECTOR_PORT="${CONNECTOR_PORT:-8080}"

# lowercase
connector_port="${CONNECTOR_PORT:-8080}"
```

It's a local variable, but then it is also read from an environment variable. I'm curious which convention people tend to follow here.

Comment: A minor consideration is that [environment variables containing lowercase letters are reserved for applications by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) so lowercase environment variable names run no risk of interfering with the behavior of standard tools and utilities. I tend to prefer lower or mixed case shell variable names for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it lower-case. Here's why:

If you do this:

```
CONNECTOR_PORT="${CONNECTOR_PORT:-8080}"
```

...then you don't know whether the `CONNECTOR_PORT` variable is flagged as exported as not. Maybe it was passed in as an environment variable, and has that flag set, or it wasn't and it doesn't. If you want to follow convention, have consistent behavior, and want keep an upper-case variable name, then you need to force it to be exported yourself:

```
export CONNECTOR_PORT="${CONNECTOR_PORT:-8080}"
```

---

If you do this:

```
connector_port="${CONNECTOR_PORT:-8080}"
```

...then it's clear that `connector_port` isn't flagged as exported to subprocesses, regardless of whether `CONNECTOR_PORT` was exported by your parent to you.

Answer (score 0):

As you already said it's a good idea to use lower case variable names inside scripts.

If I'd follow your convention then it should be lower case. From the point on where you work with the data from the evironment variable inside your script the data gets "detached" from its original scope.

In the end I'd say it's a matter of taste and maybe subjective and dependent on the point of view.